# Simple cep querying with esper framework

Tags: complex-event-processing, esper

I am trying to do some simple cep with esper. I have some fixed stream data given as a text file, my goal is when given some pattern to output for each event in the stream in how many matches it was found.

All the patterns will be determined by some fixed window length meaning they will be something like - find every A and every B following with no C in between that are no more than 6 events apart from each other (A and B are not necessarily adjacent) (of course patterns could be more complicated). 
In order to simulate this using esper's time mechanism I gave every event a count attribute - the first event has count=1 the second has count=2 and so forth and after sending each event I advance the time by 1 sec (see code). The count of the event also serves as its ID when counting in how many matches it appeared.

I grew a bit frustrated with the esper framework after few attempts did not work. I tried using pattern of the sort "every A -> every B where timer:within(X sec)", but I found that when I use this the newData object that I receive in the listener function seems to aggragate the results rather than just hold the new result each time the function is called. Plus, when using this sort of pattern after a while the running gets so slow it eventually practically stops. I also tried, using the syntax of -

```
select * from Event 
match_recognize (
   measures A as X, B as Y
   pattern (A B)
   define 
     *something*
)
```

But it is my understanding that it only matches adjacent A, B events which is not my intention.
Is there some simple way to do some fixed length window cep querying with esper? Should I try another framework? I am attaching the whole code and would welcome any help.

```
public class Main {
    static int count = 0;
    static Map<Integer, Integer> eventToOccurrences = new HashMap<>();
    static String statementName = "mystatement";
    static int toPrint = 1000;
    static int eventsNum = 9999999;

    public static void main(String[] _s) throws IOException {
        EPCompiler compiler = EPCompilerProvider.getCompiler();
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.getCommon().addEventType(Event.class);
        CompilerArguments args = new CompilerArguments(configuration);

        EPCompiled epCompiled;
        try {
            final var pattern = 
                 "select * from pattern [every e1=Event(type='A') -> every e2=Event(type='B') where timer:within(5 sec)];";
            epCompiled = compiler.compile("@name('" + statementName + "') " + pattern, args);
        }
        catch (EPCompileException ex) {
            // handle exception here
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }

        EPRuntime runtime = EPRuntimeProvider.getDefaultRuntime(configuration);
        EPDeployment deployment;
        try {
            deployment = runtime.getDeploymentService().deploy(epCompiled);
        }
        catch (EPDeployException ex) {
            // handle exception here
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }

        EPStatement statement =
                runtime.getDeploymentService().getStatement(deployment.getDeploymentId(), statementName);

        statement.addListener((newData, oldData, s, r) -> {
            final var events = ((MapEventBean) newData[0]).getProperties();
            for (var b : events.values()) {
               BeanEventBean event = (BeanEventBean)b;
               int count = (int) event.get("count");
               int occurrences = eventToOccurrences.getOrDefault(count, 0);
               eventToOccurrences.put(count, occurrences + 1);
            }
        });

        sendEvents(runtime);

        var fileName = "output.txt";
        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(fileName);
        PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(fileWriter);

        for (int count = 0; count < eventsNum; count++) {
            int occurrences = eventToOccurrences.getOrDefault(count, 0);
            printWriter.println(Integer.toString(occurrences));
        }
        printWriter.close();
    }

    static void sendEvents(EPRuntime runtime){
        BufferedReader reader;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("synthetic_FOR_TRAIN_values.txt"));
            String line = reader.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                String[] s = line.split(",");
                final var event = new Event(s[0], Double.parseDouble(s[1]), count);
                runtime.getEventService().sendEventBean(event,"Event");
                // read next line
                line = reader.readLine();
                count += 1;
                runtime.getEventService().advanceTime(count*1000);
                if(count % toPrint == 0){
                    System.out.println(Integer.toString(count));
                }
            }
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public class Event {
    private String type;
    private double value;
    private int count;

    public Event(String type, double value, int count) {
        this.type = type;
        this.value = value;
        this.count = count;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }
    public double getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things here.

Listeners receive multiple events. The listener code that you posted however only looks at "newData[0]" and ignores all other output. The listener should loop over all output events so you see all output, i..e "for (EventBean event : newData)". Otherwise you may confuse yourself if the code only prints the first output row.

The "every A -> every B" gives you all possible combinations of all A events that have ever occurred and all B events that ever occur. This means after 100 A events arrived and when a then a single B event arrives there are 100 output rows each having a the specific A-B combination. This will also run out of memory as the runtime will remember all A events that ever occurred. If you fix the listener code as I said before you would have seen this.

Your post unfortunately doesn't actually say the requirement. What is the use case? What is the expected input and expected output? No information. So I'm giving some general suggestions.

Typical pattern when the order is well defined is (add a filter to B or add a pattern guard to your liking):

```
select * from pattern [every a=A -> b=B]
```

Typical join which is handy without requiring ordering (add a where-clause or change data windows or do outer join to your liking):

```
select * from A#lastevent as a, B#lastevent as B
```

Or change the match-recognize to allow anything in between:

```
match_recognize .... pattern (A anything* B)
```

If the "preceeding" requirement is about arrival order then for example "match_recognize .... pattern (A {0,6}B C)" or "pattern[A -> [0:6]B -> C]". If the "preceeding" requirement is about comparing timestamps and events arrive out of order use join with "where A.after(B)" or similar. Joins don't care about arrival order.

Comment: So if I'd use "select * from pattern [every a=A -> b=B]", I'd eventually, after sending all events, take into account evey combination of A preceding a  B? So, similarly, if i want every combination of A preceding a B preceding a C I should use 
"select * from pattern [every a=A -> every b=B -> c=C]"?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: There is a big difference between "every a=A -> b=B" and "every a=A -> every b=B". The second every means every possible combination. An understanding of the mechanics is in the documentation "Pattern Walkthru" http://esper.espertech.com/release-8.4.0/reference-esper/html_single/index.html#pattern-walkthrough. I would use a join instead.

Comment: I need a sliding window of constant size, for example i want to find every A preceding B preceding C where A and C are no more than 6 events away from each other (i'll add more conditions eventually of course). I am a bit confused as to how the esper's syntax works so if you could give me the syntax for that that would be extemely helpful, thanks!

Comment: join with #length(6). Suggest to learn and try out different things using one of the online apps https://www.esperonline.net/

Comment: So that would look like: "select * from A#length(6) as a, B#length(6) as B, C#length(6) as c,...,F#length(6) as f"?

Comment: Joins don't care about arrival order so yes that is one way. If the "preceeding" requirement is about arrival order then for example "match_recognize .... pattern (A {0,6}B C)" or "pattern[A -> [0:6]B -> C]". If "preceeding" is about comparing timestamps and events arrive out of order use "where A.after(B)" or similar.

Comment: are you sure the syntax is "pattern[A -> [0:6]B]"? That doesn't seem to work

Comment: another issue that I've encountered is that when using the match_recognize syntax (with a pattern A B C) it would check events number 1,2 and 3 and then jump to check events 4,5 and 6; whereas i want it to check 1,2 and 3 and then check 2,3 and 4. Would appreciate any help with doing that